# graphe with tikz or pstricks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I've a second question about TikZ or Pstricks. How can I type the code to obtain like this ?  thank you

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use TikZ and its `decorations.markings` library. Please see Section 48.5, page 592+, in the TikZ3 manual, http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf. I enclose an example of this approach with help of the `postaction` option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow[scale=3]{>}}}, m/.style={blue,line width=1pt}]
\node[font=\bfseries] at (0,1.5) {Sexe};
\node[font=\bfseries] at (3,1.5) {Types d'\'etudes};
\node (f) at (0,0) {F};
\node (m) at (0,-1) {M};
\node (l) at (3.75,0.5) {Litt.};
\node (s) at (3.75,-0.5) {SC};
\node (t) at (3.75, -1.5) {Tech.};
\draw[m, postaction={decorate}] (f) to [bend left=20] (l);
\draw[m, postaction={decorate}] (m) to [bend left=20] (s);
\draw[m, postaction={decorate}] (m) to [bend left=-10] (t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 9):

Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{1.7}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c @{\hspace{1.5cm}} c @{}}
\bfseries\itshape Sexe & \bfseries\itshape Types d'\'etudes \\
                       & \rnode{l}{Litt.}                   \\
\rnode{f}{F}                                                \\
                       & \rnode{s}{SC~~}                    \\
\rnode{m}{M}                                                \\
                       & \rnode{t}{Tech.}
\end{tabular}
\psset{ArrowInside=->,ArrowInsidePos=0.7,arrowscale=2,angleB=180}
\nccurve{f}{l}  \nccurve{m}{s}  \nccurve{m}{t}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is one possible solution where `myarrow` style is defined for arrow decoration at position=0.7. One may use `bend left/right=xx`, xx=some angles of choices.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows,positioning}

\tikzset{myarrow/.style={decoration={markings,
%mark=at position 0.3 with {\arrow{stealth'}},
mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow{stealth'}}
},postaction={decorate}
}}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {Sexe};
\node[right =2cm of A] (B) {Types};

\node [below= 1cm of A](A1){F}; 
\node [below= 1.5cm of A1](A2){M};

\node [below= 1cm of B](B1){Litt}; 
\node [below= 1cm of B1](B2){SC};
\node [below= 1cm of B2](B3){Tech}; 

\draw (A1) edge[myarrow,bend left] (B1);

\draw (A2) edge[myarrow,bend left] (B2);
\draw (A2) edge[myarrow,bend right] (B3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A variant of the `pstricks` solution, using the  `makecell` package,  that produces a different alignment for the right column:

```
        \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{MinionPro}
        \pagestyle{empty}
        \usepackage{makecell}
        \renewcommand*\theadfont{\bfseries\itshape}
        \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}%
        \usepackage{pstricks-add}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip2.5cm}c}
         \thead{Sexe} & \thead{Types d'études} \\%
                        \makecell{\rnode{F}{F}\\[12pt] \rnode{M}{M}} & \makecell*{\makecell[l]{\rnode{L}{Litt.}\\[15pt] \rnode{S}{SC}\\[15pt] \rnode{T}{Tech.}}} \\
        \end{tabular}

        \psset{ArrowInside = ->, ArrowInsidePos = 0.6,linewidth = 1.5pt, linecolor = blue}
        \ncarc[nodesep = 6pt ]{F}{L}
        \nodexn{(M) + (9pt,0)}{M}
        \ncarc[nodesepA = 0pt, nodesepB = 6pt]{M}{S}
        \ncarc[ArrowInside = -<, ArrowInsidePos = 0.4,nodesepA = 6pt, nodesepB = 0pt ]{T}{M}

        \end{document}
```

[image]